# Demonstration of the mathematical expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm studying for my exam of probability distributions and in my study book got these equalities for the expectation:

[image]

I thought of using any of the two definitions to find the expectation of a random variable (continuous or discrete) but I can not reach that conclusion.

For Discrete: [image]

For Continuous: [image]

This property is true?, How I can get your deduction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get it because $\mathsf E[X]$ is just a constant, and constant is always equal to its expectation.

Comment: Yes, I noticed shortly after posting the question, thank you very much for taking the time to respond.